# Merging road segments into one road line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, merge

I have a Shapefile with a road network (lines) which includes several road segments (lines).

Is there any way to merge all these lines into one line using QGIS?

Comment: Yeah, it's called "dissolve".

Comment: Would you like to merge road segments via a specific parameter or just simply all in one? Do you need to preserve any attributes?

Comment: I just want to merge the lines so I used "dissolve" as Erik suggested. It worked fine.

Comment: Nice to hear that 

Answer (score 3):

> Tested on QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.4

I can suggest using a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have seven features in `"roads"`, see image below.

[image: Example]

With the following Query, it is possible to achieve the result

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS features,
       ST_Union(r.geometry)
FROM roads as r
```

The output Virtual Layer will create one continuous layer out of all road segments' geometries and additional field *'features'* which will count how many features were merged.

[image: Output]